# jquery ui multi dates picker: how to disable the sliding effeccT

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

In the display numberOfMonths: 3, when I click on a date in the second month, it is sliding left. Is there a possiblity to disable this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the default functionality for the JQuery UI Date Picker.  Link below.  Basically take away the animations code.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

Delete the code that looks similiar to this:
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", $( this ).val() );
    });

Comment: It is not working in this specific case. I thought that it was an animation, it is not. In multiDatePicker, the plugin  I'm using (a child of datepicker, when you click on a date in the second month, the second month becomes first, and it is really unconvenient. I tried to add the option showAnim: false, not successful...

numberOfMonths: 3,
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: false,
showAnim: false

Answer (score 0):

I have found that on [github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/issues/9](http://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/issues/9), the "slide effect" is enabled, but when you go out of the 3 selected months, it is worse than before: at each date you add, you come back to the 3 selected months.

```
onSelect:function (dateText, inst) {
    var newDate = new Date();
    inst.drawMonth = newDate.getMonth();
    inst.drawYear = newDate.getFullYear();
    inst.currentMonth = newDate.getMonth();
    inst.currentYear = newDate.getFullYear();
}
```

This piece of code put the the top-left month to be always the same on each select (in this case the current month).
So still searching...